# How to keep Sonata Admin menu on left side hidden when browsing

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

Any help will be more than welcomed.

## What are you trying to accomplish?

I have a Sonata Admin panel, and some pages have large amount of data, so I need to hide the left menu. However when I go back to another page (from a Show to a List) or I click on an action button (from a List to Show) for example, then the menu is shown again.

## Paste the part of the code that shows the problem.

I was thinking that maybe, in the same way I can keep my form filters applied even when I browse between pages (`sonata_admin.persist_filters`) maybe there is another way to set-up a global sonata parameter that will "force" the left menu to be shown or hidden for future requests, until I click on the icon to show or hide it again.

## What do you expect the result to be?

I just want to keep the left menu hidden between pages.

[Sonata Admin with collapsed menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6cHf.png)

## What is the actual result you get?

Currently, when I click on the icon next to Sonata title the menu hides, but when I browse other pages the menu is shown again.

[Sonata Admin with expanded menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAqYE.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** This is now implemented and is the standard behaviour starting from the 3.30.0 release.

---

There is no such feature currently as far as I know. You can still help us to make Sonata better by providing a PR to implement this feature.

I opened an issue to track this feature here: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/4837

Comment: Thanks Jules, that's really helpful. I can try to create a new PR for this, but please allow me to say that never sent yet a PR to Sonata Admin so I would need some time to learn where to find each file and to apply the expected settings.

Comment: @DavidGarcia This feature is now implemented.

Comment: Hi @jules-lamur much appreciated for the update! Thank you for taking care of this request.